# Add Windows partition to grub2

Tags: windows-10, opensuse, grub2

I've jsut reinstall my windows and an opensuse.
I try to add the Windows part to grub in vain.
The output of `grub2-mkconfig -o` only add my opensuse.
So I try to add Windows by my own on the grub.cfg but it's hard to understand.

Here is the output of blkid in which I found the UUID and PARTUUID :

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="RM-CM-)servM-CM-) au systM-CM-(me" UUID="568EEA0F8EE9E807" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="402550e7-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="DA4AF1B24AF18C0F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="402550e7-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="ba6300b5-2938-4d48-8dde-b907ac5d8109" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="402550e7-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="5278afd2-0840-4ecc-9ca5-9a577d28eb30" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="402550e7-05"
/dev/sda6: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="B1B3-B90D" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="402550e7-06"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="SWAP" UUID="bfc1dec6-2ef4-412a-9bc0-7b9d1136aa75" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="402550e7-07"
```

My windows is on /dev/sda2

Here is my grub.cfg mnuentry for windows :

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-DA4AF1B24AF18C0F' \
{
          insmod part_msdos
          insmod ntfs
          set root='hd0,msdos2'
          chainloader +1
}
```

When I log on it he do not find any efi file. Do I have to had a link to it on the grub.cfg ? And how ?

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *NT loader* you could just search by UUID:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows --class os {
   insmod ntfs
   insmod ntldr
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod search_fs_uuid
   search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid DA4AF1B24AF18C0F
   ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it say unable to find ntldr command

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wep, I try it thx. Now it say he can find /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi/ntldr.mod